# There is already an object named '...' in the database. Where Can I find the request?

Tags: sql-server

I have made a new request and create a new table and this error message happened.

> There is already an object named 'Employe' in the database.

How can I fix this and can anyone tell me where I can find this request? Thank you

It's a database about a market there is client order.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE TP1DB

CREATE TABLE Employe(
matricule INT IDENTITY(1,1),
nom VARCHAR(20),
prenom VARCHAR(20),
poste VARCHAR(20),
date_embauche DATE,
date_naissance DATE,
pays VARCHAR(20),
ville VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(matricule),

)

INSERT INTO Employe
VALUES ('Paré', 'Éric','Vendeur', '23-12-2020', '01-12-1985', 'Montréal', 'Canada');

CREATE TABLE Client(
numero_client INT IDENTITY(1,1),
nom VARCHAR(20),
pays VARCHAR(20),
ville VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(numero_client)
)

CREATE TABLE Commande(
no_commande INT IDENTITY(1000,1),
date_envoi DATE,
date_commande DATE,
ville_livraison VARCHAR(20),
pays_livraison VARCHAR(20),
code_postal_livraison VARCHAR(20),
a_livrer_avant DATE,
matricule INT,
numero_client INT,
PRIMARY KEY(no_commande),
FOREIGN KEY (matricule) REFERENCES Employe(matricule),
FOREIGN KEY (numero_client) REFERENCES Client(numero_client)
)

CREATE TABLE Categorie(
no_categorie INT IDENTITY(100,100),
nom_categorie VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(no_categorie)
)

INSERT INTO Categorie 
VALUES ('Tablette');

CREATE TABLE Fournisseur(
no_fournisseur INT IDENTITY(1,1),
nom_fournisseur VARCHAR(20),
pays VARCHAR(20),
ville VARCHAR(20),
no_commande INT,
PRIMARY KEY(no_fournisseur)
)

INSERT INTO Fournisseur
VALUES ('Samsung', 'États-Unis', 'Boston');

CREATE TABLE Produit(
no_produit INT IDENTITY(1,1),
nom_produit VARCHAR(20),
prix_unitaire MONEY,
unites_en_stock INT,
no_fournisseur INT,
no_categorie INT,
PRIMARY KEY(no_produit),
FOREIGN KEY (no_fournisseur) REFERENCES Fournisseur(no_fournisseur),
FOREIGN KEY (no_categorie) REFERENCES Categorie(no_categorie)
)

INSERT INTO Produit
VALUES ('Galaxy tab2', 249, 9, 1),
('Sumsung 15', 399, 0, 1 );
```

Comment: Multiple questions but not one answer marked. Do your part for the free assistance you seek and are given. Your first problem is that after creating the database (your first statement), you need to change the current database of the connection to your new database. To do that, you need to add "USE TP1DB" as the second statement and "GO" as the third statement. Without those, you will create your tables in whichever database you are currently connect to - and you have probably done this multiple times so have scattered multiple versions of this schema throughout your database instance.

Comment: Yeah, like SMor said, you are probably working on master database if your never did ```Use TP1DB```. Sa ressemble drôlement à un travail pratique de Cégep ça héhé

Comment: Ça l'ai. J'uttilisais MariaDB dans ma première session et on faisait just des SELECT. C'est la première que je créer une table avec Microsoft donc j'étais un peu bloquer et ma professeur est occupée avec sa famille donc j'avais pas beaucoup d'option haha. Akina thank you very much I didn't know that I had to do the solved option sorry about that I will do it now. ^^

Comment: It's also good to qualify the owner of your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Employe table already exists in your database. You can use the `Select * From Employe` query to see what it contains. If it's a useless table, you can delete it and re-run your code to create it. If you want to delete it, you can use `DROP TABLE Employe`

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the Object Explorer window tree to see the contents of a database

[image]

Comment: I did these commands 

```
CREATE DATABASE TP1DB
USE TP1DB
GO
DROP TABLE Employe;` but I still have that error message ``Database 'TP1DB' already exists. Choose a different database name.`` And In what folder I can find the existing database ?

Comment: @MrBigboka Ok, now you can run all your script except for your first line ```CREATE DATABASE TP1DB```. If you still get the same error, you probably have tables with the same name already created, then you will only be able to execute your insert statements. Remember that if you are not sure if a table exists, the command ```SELECT * FROM your_table_name``` will give you an error if the table does not exist, otherwise it will give you its contents.

Comment: @MrBigboka 
Your message is clear, the TP1DB database already exists, so you can just use ```USE TP1DB GO``` and create your tables. Once you have executed ```CREATE DATABASE TP1DB```, you cannot re-execute this command.

Comment: @MrBigboka In SQL Server Management Studio, you can see the existing database in the Object Explorer window -> under your server name -> under Databases.

Comment: Oh ok so if I use the request one time I can delete it and all I need to do is to find the database ?

Comment: Je me permet d'écrire en français sa me semble ta langue maternelle, De quelle requête que tu parle ? Si tu veux supprimer une table dans la base de donnés TP1DB, tu peux utiliser ```Use TP1DB GO; DROP TABLE EMPLOYE``` et après si tu veux la recréer tu peux ré-executer ```CREATE TABLE Employe(
matricule INT IDENTITY(1,1),
nom VARCHAR(20),
prenom VARCHAR(20),
poste VARCHAR(20),
date_embauche DATE,
date_naissance DATE,
pays VARCHAR(20),
ville VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(matricule)

)``` C'est sa que tu voulais dire ?

Comment: Je voulais dire une fois que j'ai executé les commandes pour créer la table je peux tout supprimé et commencer à faire mes SELECT ? Et puis pour trouver la database en question je n'arrivais à trouver "window" dans  "Object Explorer"

Comment: @MrBigboka Une fois que tu as créer tes tables, pourquoi tu voudrais tout supprimé ?

Comment: Je veux dire supprimer mes requêtes pas mes tables. Et je n'ai pas réussi à trouver le fichier avec les tables..

Comment: @MrBigboka j'ai mis une image dans ma réponse plus haute, tu ce qui est dans le carré rouge ce sont mes tables

Comment: Merci je l'ai trouver ! Mais dans le dossier tables je vois uniquement la table employé et pas les autres tables c'est normal ?

Comment: Je viens de voir que ma requête à uniquement créer une seule table alors que j'en n'ai écris plusieurs. Est-ce qu'il manque des ``;``?

Comment: J'ai répondu à ma propre question merci quand même !